# Rotate graphic object by 360 degrees

Tags: java, android, math, geometry

I have two points(x1,x2,y1,y2) they are forming a vertical line. When user is rotating object I know these two points, the question is: How do I find the coordinates of the other two points which are forming a horizontal line. How it easier to implement? I would be grateful for any help!
 [image: example object]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is really a geometry question, not a programming question.

Comment: @JimGarrison Look at tags. Also maybe this question have an easier solution

Comment: I know, but questions purely about geometry are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is:

```
[cos(a) -sin(a)]
[sin(a)  cos(a)]
```

So for `x,y` rotated is:

```
rx = x*cos(a) + y*sin(a);
ry = -x*sin(a) + y*cos(a);
```

Because the other line is at 90 degrees, this evaluates to:

```
rx = y;
ry = -x;
```

So:

```
(x1,x2,y1,y2) => (y1,y2,-x1,-x2)
```

I would use the [`Point`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) class to store it and put this in a method:

```
public static Point Rotate90(Point point){
     return new Point(point.y, -point.x);
}
```

Now that's a rotation about the origin, if your line needs to touch the other, then you will need to translate before and after.

```
p = x,y
pr = centre of rotation
```

Rotate `p` about `pr`:

```
Rotate90(p - pr) + pr
```

In a method:

```
public static Point Rotate90(Point point, Point about){
     Point translated = new Point(point.x - about.x, point.y - about.y);
     Point rotated = Rotate90(translated);
     return new Point(rotated.x + about.x, rotated.y + about.y);
}
```

Comment: many thanks! I will try it today and comment/accept!